# How to add filter in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat, genymotion

when I want to read LogCat in eclipse ide I see a lot of `logcat` error.

How can i solve these errors ?

*this is a picture of logCat genymoyion error*

[image]

Comment: The errors won't be doing any harm, you can just suppress them (filter them using DDMS): http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add filter

[image: Add filter]

There's a button that looks like a green + in the upper right of the log cat window, if you mouse over it says "Create Filter" in the popup from that you can filter by log tag. It creates a new tab in log cat with the filter name you specified. Then all of the output of that tag will go to that tab and not the "Log" tab.

Specify names

[image]

Choose your filter.

In the Eclipse environment, in the LogCat view, above the table there is a search box.
Pay attention, when empty it reads:

> Search for messages. Accepts Java regexes. Prefix with pid:, app:,
>   tag: or text: to limit scope.

It means you can filter your tag by writing there **tag:MyTag** or even regex **tag:My.***

[image]

Comment: when I filter logs with this way or app:mypackage logCat show me nothing and there is a free logCat box.but when I filter logs with tag:mayTag I can see my app tags.how can I see my app tags with this way : app:myPackage ?

Comment: @FakhraneNassiry what is your `package` name ?

Comment: for e.g. : nassiry.fakhrane.my_app

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the logs from Logcat using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html). Just select your desired process like the app you are developing to get the specific logs of your app only.